# eslint errors on .js files

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

My codebase is full of `.js` files and I am running `eslint` on a particular file.
I get below errors:

```
 1:8   error  'React' is defined but never used
                              no-unused-vars
1:27  error  Trailing spaces not allowed
                              no-trailing-spaces
2:1   error  'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run
'npm i -S prop-types' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
7:13  error  Arrow function used ambiguously with a conditional expression
                              no-confusing-arrow
11:3   error  Prop type `array` is forbidden
                              react/forbid-prop-types
```

My `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
  },
  plugins: [
    'react'
  ],
  rules: {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
  },
};
```

My `Package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
    "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "2.11.15",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint": "3.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "10.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.1.5",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "husky": "^3.0.5",
    "lint-staged": "^3.2.1",
    "ngrok": "2.2.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "standard-version": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
}
```

I tried with various solutions below:

```
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/
var React = require('react');
/*eslint-enable no-unused-vars*/
```

And:

```
var React = require('react');    // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

but can't do it for almost 300-500 files.

expectations is to resolve all the errors thrown in `.js` files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the desired result? Do you want the errors to show on .jsx files aswel? Or do you need help fixing your eslint errors on your .js files only?

Comment: @Luze expectations is to resolve all the errors thrown in .js files.

Comment: but is it because of the .js extension ?

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue between .js or .jsx. Functionally there is no difference and both filetypes should be completely interchangeable. Although there is a possibility that eslint doesn't like the .js file extension on react components as it is a common rule to not use .js extensions for files which are not strictly javascript. But I can't tell you for a fact that this is the issue here.

Comment: so how do we handle these error in js files ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what each of those errors mean and how to fix them:

---

**`1:8   error  'React' is defined but never used`:**

Eslint `no-unused-vars` rule doesn't recognise variables used in JSX. 
Change your `eslint` rules from this:

```
rules: {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
},
```

To this:

```
rules: {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1
},
```

---

**`1:27  error  Trailing spaces not allowed`**

You have a trailing space somewhere on line `27` at the end of your line, remove it and the error should go away.

---

**`2:1   error  'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run
'npm i -S prop-types' to add it`**

`prop-types` isn't listed in your `package.json` as a dependency. This one is pretty straight forward to fix, like the error suggests. Run `npm i -S prop-types` in your terminal to add it to your `package.json`.

---

**`7:13  error  Arrow function used ambiguously with a conditional expression`**

It's quite hard to fix this one without seeing the line of code where this error throws from. But my guess is that you are using a `conditional expression` in an `arrow function`, something like this:

`const arrow = (boolean) => boolean ? true : false`

Wrap your function in parens to fix this issue like this:

`const arrow = (boolean) => ( boolean ? true : false )`

Or this:

`const arrow = (boolean) => { return boolean ? true : false }`

---

**`11:3   error  Prop type`array`is forbidden`**

`Eslint` wants you to use `arrayOf` instead of `array` in your `prop-types`:

Something like this:
`arrayOf(string)`

Answer (score 1):

`npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`

In your `.eslintrc.json`, under extends, include the following plugin:

```
{
 "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```